# Android Async Execution comes after onCreate

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, simpleadapter

I'm really new to android application creation and I'm using Android studio to work on my project. I'm fetching json result from my db and the fetched result are what I want, but I do not know how to let asynctask to finish before onCreate. My ListView are empty but I confirmed with debugger that my asynctask result values exist.

updated: I trace error to here:

```
  public void populatedata(){
            /**get back result from pref**/
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String result =pref.getString("result", "null");
        try{
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: "+result);

            JSONObject person = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = person.getJSONArray("result");
            final int n = jsonMainNode.length();

            ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            String[] from = new String[] {"id", "time"};
            int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

            List<Map<String,String>> classList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

         //   for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
                  //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         //       JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

          //      String id = jsonChildNode.getString("id");
           //     String schedule = jsonChildNode.getString("schedule");
           //     String time = jsonChildNode.getString("time");
            //    String output = schedule + time;
               // classList.add(createchild(id,output));
              //  Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value before loop: "+classList);
          //  }
          //  Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value after loop: "+classList);
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here5");


            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", "time" + i);
                map.put("col_1", "col_1_item_" + i);
                map.put("col_2", "col_2_item_" + i);
                map.put("col_3", "col_3_item_" + i);
                classList.add(map);
            }

            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,classList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
            lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private HashMap<String, String>createchild(String id,String output){
        HashMap<String,String> childNo = new HashMap<String,String>();

        childNo.put(id,output);
        Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here4");
        return childNo;

    }

the // for loop is the one i wanna work it out, and my string result `is{"result":[{"id":"00000000001","schedule":"000001","time":"10:21:37"}]}`


updated: It's my mistake, I did not create a R.layout and textview for it, I learned to use custom adapter and create an external layout.

public class ViewClassActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_class);

        /**prepare list**/
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String id =pref.getString("userid", "null");



        Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here");
        new fetchclass(this,id).execute(id);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    public void getdata(String result){
        //save preferences
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putString("result", result);  // Saving result string

        Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here3");
        // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
        editor.apply(); // apply changes
        populatedata();

        Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here6");
    }

    public void populatedata(){
        /**get back result from pref**/
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String result =pref.getString("result", "null");
        Log.d("ADebugTag",result);

        try{
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: "+result);

            JSONObject person = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = person.getJSONArray("result");
            final int n = jsonMainNode.length();

            ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            String[] from = new String[] {"id", "schedule"};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView20,R.id.textView21};

            //List<Map<String,String>> classList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> classList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = jsonChildNode.getString("id");
                String schedule = jsonChildNode.getString("schedule");
                String time = jsonChildNode.getString("time");
                String output = schedule + time;

                hashMap.put("id", id);
                hashMap.put("schedule", output);

                classList.add(hashMap);
                //classList.add(createchild(id,output));
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value before loop: "+classList);
            }

           CustomAdapter simpleAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,classList, R.layout.list_view_item, from, to);
            lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private HashMap<String, String>createchild(String id,String output){
        HashMap<String,String> childNo = new HashMap<String,String>();

        childNo.put(id,output);
        Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here4");
        return childNo;

    }
```

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="Demo1"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="Demo2"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView20" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = data;
        inflater.from(context);
    }



}
```

figured out my issue using this site, and thanks for everybody for the help:

[custom-listview](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-simpleadapter.html)

Comment: Because when async is executed background thread is started (post result with onPost()) and program moves to next line...and as I can see your listview is populated with adapter even before background task in completed...one solution I would seggest is to set adapter after your task is finished i.e call `SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,classList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"result"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
` after `populatedata();` in your `getdata(String result)` and check for results

Comment: @Mohit your suggest work! my debugger now show me that code run the sequence I want to! but I'm still facing empty listview! could it be the reason of the hasmap generated?
the string value i obtain is **{"result":[{"id":"00000000001","schedule":"000001","time":"10:21:37"}]}**
but after hasmap it is **[{00000000001=00000110:21:37}]**

and btw post your answer below so I can mark it as a tick, you solve the most fundamental of my question although my listview still blank

Comment: *First:* please update code so it is convenient to analys.............. *Second:*  Yes , you are right , every time you are calling `createchild()` in loop you are initializing hashmap and you get new empty hashmap..just declare global hashmap variable and initialize it once (say at onCreate() or some where but not in loop) and call it in method ...hope it helps

Comment: but i thought my hasmap method is out of the loop? or you mean this part?`String time = jsonChildNode.getString("time");
                String output = schedule + time;
                classList.add(createchild(id,output));
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: "+classList);
            }`
bring the **createchild(id,output));** out of the loop? but, how?

Comment: just remove `HashMap<String,String> childNo = new HashMap<String,String>();` from `createchild()` and put it at top of your class i.e below `List<Map<String,String>> classList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();`

Comment: ok updated: i made a debugger before and after loop and throw in and out the initialize of my hashmap, both are showing the values, no different, i wonder if its my simpleadapter line is the problem here

Comment: `how to let asynctask to finish before onCreate` you can't, that's what async means.

Comment: Actually that depend on the data you are fetching...but if you have have low data to fetch .. still there is no guaranty that async will finish before program goes to next line as it is a thread and is made to run in background so it will still execute in background and follow the procedure (onPre() -> doInBackground() -> onPost()..etc)....the good way to use it is...show progress bar before starting aync and when it completes (onPost()) populate the listview with data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't let the async task finish before onCreate.  That's the entire point of an async task-  it executes in parallel.  Instead you should put up a loading screen (even just something as simple as an indeterminate progress bar) to show the user you're waiting for data, then load the data into the list in onPostExecute of the task.

Comment: It will make your life much easier if you use an event bus to work with async tasks. http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/

Comment: Do NOT use an event bus for async tasks.  That just brings about horrible spaghetti code.  If you ever need to use an event bus it means that you completely midsdesigned your code.

Comment: Why is an event bus a bad thing?

Comment: Because it hides the actual flow of the application, making debugging more difficult.  Its nearly impossible to figure out who actually responds to events when without actually running the program.  Its basically a giant goto-  and we've been saying goto is bad since the 60s.

Comment: so just progress dialog wont do?

Comment: @GabeSechan how about I used what Mohit suggested? the debugger that I saw is running the sequence I want after I follow it, but the listview is still blank, I'm wondering is it because of the simpleadapter cannot be placed in method except inside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 public class ViewClassActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


List<Map<String,String>> classList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_class);

    /**prepare list**/
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String id =pref.getString("userid", "null");

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,classList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"result"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here5");

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here");
    new fetchclass(this,id).execute(id);
}

private HashMap<String, String>createchild(String id,String output){
    HashMap<String,String> childNo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    childNo.put(id,output);
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here4");
    return childNo;

}

public class fetchclass  extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

ProgressDialog proDialog;
String userid;

public ViewClassActivity activity;


public fetchclass(ViewClassActivity a, String id) {

    this.activity = a;
    this.userid = id;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
    //pre-execute procedure
    // Showing progress loading dialog
    proDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    proDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    proDialog.setCancelable(false);
    proDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try{
        String id = arg0[0];

        String link="http://www.commcreative.me/mnas/attendance.php";
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write( data );
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }

        try{
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: "+sb.toString(););

            JSONObject person = new JSONObject(sb.toString(););
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = person.getJSONArray("result");
            final int n = jsonMainNode.length();

            for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = jsonChildNode.getString("id");
                String schedule = jsonChildNode.getString("schedule");
                String time = jsonChildNode.getString("time");
                String output = schedule + time;
                classList.add(createchild(id,output));
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: "+classList);
            }

            simpleAdapter .notifyDataSetChange();

        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (proDialog.isShowing())
        proDialog.dismiss();
    //dismiss end

   // Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here2");
    // activity.getdata(result);

}
}

private HashMap<String, String>createchild(String id,String output){
    HashMap<String,String> childNo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    childNo.put(id,output);
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Hi, Im here4");
    return childNo;

}



}
```

Comment: there exists alot of error in fetchdata class 
e.g:
'code'Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: "+sb.toString(););

            JSONObject person = new JSONObject(sb.toString(););'code'
the ; unexpected token, and the simpleadapter method cannot be resolved. Sorry, I don't really know how to handle simpleadapter this thing.

Comment: Use this link it will surely solve your problem.https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html

Comment: it doesnt teach array, or listview, this is non looping method which i hav no issue